# Primary Key doesn't have a default value in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do the simplest thing in MySQL and getting an error. I create a table running this query.

```
create table STATION
( ID int NOT NULL
, CITY varchar(21)
, STATE varchar(2)
, LAT_N int
, LONG_N int
, primary key(ID) );
```

Now I'm trying to insert some data into the table,

```
INSERT INTO STATION 
(CITY, STATE, LAT_N, LONG_N) VALUES 
("Buffalo", "NY", 123, 233);
```

This is the error that I get,
`ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'ID' doesn't have a default value`

Isn't ID supposed to default at 0 and autoincrement?

Comment: *Isn't ID supposed to default at 0 and autoincrement?*, well, not really. If you don't make it auto-increment, it simply won't be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should make your ID `AUTO_INCREMENT`

```
create table STATION(
  ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  CITY VARCHAR(21),
  STATE VARCHAR(2),
  LAT_N INT,
  LONG_N INT,
  PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to specify that you want an auto increment field.

```
ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

Your id can be, for instance, a composite id and then a non autoincrement id.

More information at https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp

Answer (score 2):

Primary keys are supposed to be unique in value. So you won't want to set a default static value to the id as that wouldn't work after the first insert. A good practice will be to use an auto_incrementable id instead.

```
create table STATION(
 ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 CITY varchar(21), 
 STATE varchar(2), 
 LAT_N int, 
 LONG_N int
);
```